# Grails "remember me" not working

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I am using [Grails Spring Security Plugin 2.0 RC2](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core).

When I enabled (out-of-the-box privided) functionlaity by adding checkbox in login form.

The cookie is created properly (with time 2 weeks ahead), but Remember-me mechanism does not work in two cases:

- When I close the browser, the remember me cookie dissapears. Why?
- When I delete JSESSIONID cookie, the session is not regenated.

In addition: I don't want to use persistent remember me that requires storing tokens in db. I want to rely on cookie-based remember me strategy.

Comment: I saw this post before asking, but as I mentioned: I don't want to use persistent remember me that requires storing tokens in db. I want to rely on cookie-based remember me strategy. In this post token repository is used.

Answer (score 2):

This plagued me for the entire day, but I was using Spring Security Plugin 1.2.7.3.

For me, it was that the authentication provider was missing from the config. For example:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = [
      'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider',
      'daoAuthenticationProvider',
      'ldapAuthProvider',
      'anonymousAuthenticationProvider']
```

'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider' was the missing link. I discovered this when setting the log level to trace for all things related to what I was doing:

```
trace 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme',
      'org.springframework.security.web.authentication',
      'org.springframework.security.web',
      'org.springframework.security'
```

I saw this in the output (note the bold):

> 2014-01-21 13:10:59,490 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG
>   rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices  - Remember-me cookie detected
>
> 2014-01-21 13:10:59,545 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG
>   rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices  - Remember-me cookie accepted
>
> 2014-01-21 13:10:59,582 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG
>   rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter  - SecurityContextHolder not
>   populated with remember-me token, as AuthenticationManager rejected
>   Authentication returned by RememberMeServices:
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken@7651888e:
>   Principal:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUser@d008d6e3:
>    invalidating remember-me token
>
> **Message: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken**
>
> 2014-01-21 13:10:59,638 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG
>   rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices  - Interactive login attempt
>   was unsuccessful.
>
> 2014-01-21 13:10:59,638 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG
>   rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices  - Cancelling cookie

As an fyi, removing the JSESSIONID cookie is essentially the same as closing the browser: http://muras.eu/index.html%3Fp=673.html

Hope that helps!

Comment: "removing the JSESSIONID cookie is essentially the same as closing the browser"
This saved a lot of toll from my end because now I have a quick way to test the remember me function(without having to wait for hours)

Answer (score 1):

The thing that bit me was that I also had the Spring Security Open ID plugin installed for some logins.  That changes the remember me functionality to be a no-op in the `SpringSecurityOpenidGrailsPlugin` file unless you're using persistent `rememberMe`:

```
if (!conf.rememberMe.persistent) {
    // auth is external, so no password, so regular cookie isn't possible
    rememberMeServices(NullLogoutHandlerRememberMeServices)
}
```

If you debug in the `GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter` and see that the injected `rememberMeServices` object is the `NullLogoutHanderlRememberMeServices` one, you know what's going on.  That version has all actions as no-ops.

You want either the in-memory `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` or persistent `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` for it to actually work.